# AJUDA EM C PLIS --> Estou querendo criar uma matriz em uma função e retorna-la totalmente preenchida, porém no meu código ele retorna null

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>


char * criar_matriz() {

  char *matriz[8][10] = {};
  matriz [7][3] = "*";
  matriz [7][4] = "*";  
  matriz [7][5] = "*";
  matriz [7][6] = "*";

  for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
        matriz[i][j] = " ";
}
  }
 for(int l = 1; l<3; l++) {
for(int c = 2; c<=6; c++) {
    matriz[l][c] = "#";
    printf("%s\n", matriz[l][c]);
    }
  }
   return matriz[8][10];
}

 void elegante (char *matriz[8][10]) {
  for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
      printf("%s", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}



int main() {
  char *matriz[8][10]= {};
  matriz[8][10] = criar_matriz();
  elegante(matriz);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Primeiro você tem certeza de quer definir uma matriz de ponteiros para char ou na realidade quer declarar uma matriz de char? Segundo: estude sobre escopo de variáveis. Da forma como está fazendo a matriz é desalocada ao final da execução da função.

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** GetMatriz(const int L, const int C) {

    char** matriz;

    matriz = (char**) malloc ( L * sizeof(char*) );

    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++) {

        matriz[i] = (char*) malloc( C * sizeof(char) );

        for(int j = 0; j < C; j++) {

            matriz[i][j] = '*';

        }
    }

    return matriz;

}


int main() {

    char** matriz = GetMatriz(10, 10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

            printf("%c ", matriz[i][j]);

        }

        printf("\n");

    }


    return 0;
}
```